# Default timeout seconds for AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsurlconnection, nsurl

In my project I have used AFNetworking for Api calls, How to identify the default timeout seconds for AFNetworking. Please suggest.

Comment: And *please* show your attempts to solve your problem.

Comment: Default timeout seconds : 60

Answer (score 16, accepted):

the default timeout for `AFNetwork` is **60 seconds**

> The timeout interval, in seconds. If during a connection attempt the
>   request remains idle for longer than the timeout interval, the request
>   is considered to have timed out. The default timeout interval is 60
>   seconds.

additional [reference](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1897)

if you want to decrease the timeout

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"par1": @"value1",
                     @"par2": @"value2"};

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:25];  //Time out after 25 seconds

[manager POST:@"URL" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

//Success call back bock
NSLog(@"Request completed with response: %@", responseObject);


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
 //Failure callback block. This block may be called due to time out or any other failure reason
}];
```